# Knitr::kable formatting troubles and data display

Tags: r, knitr

I was plotting models based on distance and i now want to compare the AIC's of my models and the goodness of fit tests.

I have to do this using the Knitr:kable function in Rstudio. Only i seem to run into the problem that my table format is wrong. The data is skewered and almost unreadable. How do i fix this?
Running my code i get the table below but this is not what i want it to look like. This is how it is supposed to look: [image: Example Knitr::kable model comparison]

```
knitr::kable(summarize_ds_models(TD2S1WP.hn.cos, TD2S1WP.unif.cos, TD2S1WP.hnr.poly))


|Model                     |Key function                                      |Formula | C-vM 
p-value| $\hat{P_a}$| se($\hat{P_a}$)| $\Delta$AIC|
|:-------------------------|:-------------------------------------------------|:-------|------ 
------:|-----------:|---------------:|-----------:|
|\texttt{TD2S1WP.hn.cos}   |Half-normal                                       |~1      |    
0.0988482|   0.3391492|       0.0408983|    0.000000|
|\texttt{TD2S1WP.unif.cos} |Uniform with cosine adjustment terms of order 1,2 |NA      |    
0.0896416|   0.3732953|       0.0420456|    1.667653|
|\texttt{TD2S1WP.hnr.poly} |Hazard-rate                                       |~1      |    
0.0492042|   0.4460613|       0.0424159|    3.577427|
```

How do i fix this problem? thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this RMarkdown or Quarto document,  plain R script ... or are you executing it from R 
 console as `>` prompt might suggest?

Comment: Hi, this code was written in Rstudio. The example for the code i am using comes from a example dataset but i can't seem to get the format to work in Rstudio. 
The package that was used in Rstudio to generate the models that are compared here is the R package Distance.
Example sheet: https://examples.distancesampling.org/Distance-lines/lines-distill.html

Comment: But what is the actual project or file type ( *RStudio : File -> New file  -> ...* ) you are using? You generally get rendered tables with Markdown-based formats that support live preview and/or require rendering/knitting to produce pdf, html or other output types.

Comment: I'm sorry i am very new with RStudio. When i followe the steps i did file -> New file -> R script. And that is what i'm working with. Or in the console part of Rstudio

Comment: For a document that includes charts, tables and text, choose Quarto instead. Or R Notebook / R Markdown. You may want to familiarize yourself with the concept first - https://r4ds.hadley.nz/quarto.html (includes `knitr::kable()` example ), https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/code/execution.html#computational-documents , https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/rstudio.html .